# React TypeScript 16.8 How to share data between two sibling components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React 16.8 with TypeScript and functional components I can't understand how a parent component can pass data from one child to another. I have setup the parent that loads two components `ShowCompanyName` and `EnterCompanyName` I can pass a prop to the `ShowCompanyName` with the correct type and it displays just fine. What I want to do is enter a company name into the input in `EnterCompanyName` and have it displayed in `ShowCompanyName` without using Redux and enforcing the correct types as we go.

Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ShowCompanyName from '../components/show';
import EnterCompanyName from '../components/enter';

const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <EnterCompanyName></EnterCompanyName>
      <ShowCompanyName companyName="My Pet Shop"></ShowCompanyName>
   </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

Show Component

```
import React from 'react';

type AppProps = {
    companyName?: string
  }

const ShowCompanyName: React.FC<AppProps> = ({companyName = 'Default Name'}) => {
  return (
       <p>{companyName}</p>
  );
}

export default ShowCompanyName;
```

Enter Component

```
import React from 'react';


const EnterCompanyName: React.FC = () => {
  return (
       <p><input type="string" name='companyName'/></p>
  );
}

export default EnterCompanyName;
```

Comment: You can use `useState` in `<Parent>` to manage the state of the company name. You then can pass this state's value as props to `<ShowCompanyName>` and an `onChange` function that changes the value of the company name as props to `<EnterCompanyName>`. Here is a demo on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/share-data-between-children-ipb6x).

Comment: Thank you for you CodeSandox I can see how the data flows now but TypeScript s is throwing errors. In Parent I get `Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)` and `Type '{ onChange: (event: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)` and then in the show component I get `Property 'onChange' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)`

Comment: All of those compilation errors have nothing to do with the question you've posed. You need global state management if you want to do complex data passing between parent -> children, children -> parent, and children -> children of a shared parent. I suggest redux, but the context api also works